# Question regarding finding the formula for Alignment of Polar Molecule

Tags: electrostatics, dipole

In the section *4.1.3 Alignment of Polar Molecules* of Griffiths’s *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, when the change in electric field is found $ΔE_x=(\nabla E_x)\cdot \mathbf{d}$.

I don't understand this part: why are we finding the *gradient* of $E_x$, and finding its dot product with $\mathbf{d}$ (distance between the charges)?

[image: Alignment of Polar Molecule .]

Answer (score 1):

It follow by taking the first order of Taylor expansion. Call $E_i$ the $i$ component of your electric field, you have:

\begin{align}
\Delta E_i & \simeq  \frac{\partial E_i}{\partial x} \Delta x+\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial y} \Delta y+\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial z} \Delta z \\
           &=\Delta \vec{r} \cdot \nabla E_i , \quad \Delta \vec{r} \equiv (\Delta x ,\Delta y, \Delta z)
\end{align}
in your case you have $\Delta \vec{r}=\vec{d}$ from wich you conclude the proof.

Comment: I don't understand why $Δ\vec r=\vec d$ .Are we calculating how the Electric field changes when as we go from the negative charge to the positive charge ?

Comment: Yes, in fact you are calculating $\Delta E_i$

Comment: Ok so the displacement here is the distance between the charges .Is the gradient of the E field along x direction too ?

Comment: No, gradient can be in a generic direction in particular whose direction point towards the maximum value of E_i near $x_0$.